# SVN Access Control is working wrong

Tags: svn

I have multiple repositories with multiple users in SVN, I created the user groups and permissions assigned to each of the repositories, but configuration is not working properly. At the moment the only way it works is by assigning read / write access to all repositories.

```
[/]
* = rw
```

The original content of my file access control is as follows:

```
[groups]
administration = adminone, admintwo
roleone = user1, user2
roletwo = user3
rolethree = @roleone, @roletwo

[/]
* = r
@administration = rw

[/project1]
@roleone = rw

[/project2]
@roleone = rw

[/project3]
user1 = rw

[/project4]
@roletwo = rw
```

The problem is user1 can read all repositories but cannot make a commit to project3 nor project1 nor project2.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Read [SVNBook | Path-Based Authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) chapter first. It looks like that the syntax of the access control file you use is incorrect.

If project1, project2, project3, project4 are repositories, then you should specify access rules for them like this

```
[Project1:/]
user=rw
```